# How to migrate from mysql 5.1 to 5.5?

Tags: mysql, migration

I am just migrating from 5.1 to 5.5.
I copy my data from mysql5.1 data forlder to mysql5.5/data.

I just wondered if I can overwrite the file **ibdata1** in mysql 5.5 data directory?

Thanks Arman.

**EDIT**

Yes I can copy 5.1 to 5.5 and then I need to run **mysql_upgrade**

Comment: Is there any special reason you are not using dumps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you visited the [MySQL 5.5 FAQ: Migration](https://web.archive.org/web/20170630093954/https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-migration.html) portion of the reference manual? They have a specific page dedicated to [moving from 5.1 to 5.5](https://web.archive.org/web/20171014141331/http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading.html) with step-by-step guide (including making a backup).

Comment: the links are dead now, 5.6 and later are still there but information on 5.5 and earlier are hard to come by

Comment: @m02ph3u5 5.5 support ended 2018. 5.6 is scheduled to end this month (Feb 2021). I would _hope_ these versions aren't being actively used, and upgrades were already performed.

Comment: oh, in some businesses moving from Oracle DB 8 to MySQL 5.1 is a big *upgrade* ...

Comment: Updated to working (archived) links.